# Spring Boot RequestMapping not working on Linux Fedora 26

Tags: java, linux, spring, maven, spring-boot

I recently started using Linux Fedora 26 and wanted to start a Spring Boot Application but it won't recognize @Controller and @RestController annotations with Thymeleaf. My HomeController class's mapping doesn't see my Templates folder and I get a Whiteable Error page / 404. 
I have started to build a similar project (https://github.com/alexanderphoen1x/trainingdiary) in my old Windows machine and it seemed to work fine, but when I tried running my old project, I cloned it from github and it gives me an Exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource  

[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed
```

I think it might be Linux related?

Project structure:

```
1. greenenergy
    -src/main/java
        +com.greenenergy
            *GreenEnergyApplication.java
        +com.greenenergy.controller
            *HomeController.java
    -src/main/resources
        +static
        +templates
            *stories.html
        +application.properties
(...)
    -pom.xml
```

My code:
GreenEnergyApplication.java:

```
package com.greenenergy;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GreenEnergyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreenEnergyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

HomeController.java:

```
package com.greenergy.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String stories() {
        return "stories";
    }
}
```

stories.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title></title>
<head></head>
<body>Hey Alex</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.greenenergy</groupId>
    <artifactId>greenenergy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Green energy project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Console:

```
2018-10-22 17:31:32.580  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] com.greenenergy.GreenEnergyApplication   : Starting GreenEnergyApplication on localhost.localdomain with PID 5091 (/home/alexanderp/Projects/greenenergy/greenenergy/target/classes started by alexanderp in /home/alexanderp/Projects/greenenergy/greenenergy)
2018-10-22 17:31:32.581  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] com.greenenergy.GreenEnergyApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-10-22 17:31:32.650  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@76dffce0: startup date [Mon Oct 22 17:31:32 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-22 17:31:34.411  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-10-22 17:31:34.438  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-10-22 17:31:34.439  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2018-10-22 17:31:34.446  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version [1.6.3].
2018-10-22 17:31:34.447  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2018-10-22 17:31:34.447  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2018-10-22 17:31:34.450  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0h-fips  27 Mar 2018]
2018-10-22 17:31:34.546  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-10-22 17:31:34.546  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1900 ms
2018-10-22 17:31:34.619  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-10-22 17:31:34.623  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-22 17:31:34.624  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-22 17:31:34.624  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-22 17:31:34.624  INFO 5091 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-22 17:31:34.785  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-22 17:31:35.027  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@76dffce0: startup date [Mon Oct 22 17:31:32 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-22 17:31:35.117  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-10-22 17:31:35.119  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-10-22 17:31:35.177  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-22 17:31:35.177  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-22 17:31:35.425  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-10-22 17:31:35.453  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-10-22 17:31:35.482  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-10-22 17:31:35.487  INFO 5091 --- [  restartedMain] com.greenenergy.GreenEnergyApplication   : Started GreenEnergyApplication in 3.246 seconds (JVM running for 4.164)
2018-10-22 17:31:40.437  INFO 5091 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-10-22 17:31:40.437  INFO 5091 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-10-22 17:31:40.450  INFO 5091 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 12 ms
2018-10-22 17:31:48.845  INFO 5091 --- [       Thread-7] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@76dffce0: startup date [Mon Oct 22 17:31:32 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-22 17:31:48.848  INFO 5091 --- [       Thread-7] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: Please share error logs/console logs

Comment: It logs 1 warning: 
The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration is never used GreenEnergyApplication.java /greenenergy/src/main/java/com/greenenergy line 4 Java Problem

Comment: Can you please add your package structure?

Comment: Can you provide your maven and java version please. Share also the commands you use to build and run your project.

Comment: Java jre-jdk version: 
jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-3.b10.fc26.x86_64
I build my project from Spring Tool Suite 4 -> Run as Spring Boot Application

Comment: just to be sure this is not coming from STS (that i don't know well), do you have the same error when running the app using `mvn spring-boot:run` ?

Answer (score 0):

The Maven dependency could be corrupted during the download. Comment out the Thymeleaf in the POM and save the project. Delete manually the Thymeleaf files on your drive. Put back the Thymeleaf dependency in the POM and save the Project.